# Search file for no more than two occurrences of string

Tags: regex, bash, macos, unix

For a university course we have a file that has lines like

```
Word Word Word
Word Word
Text Word
Word Worden Word Word someothertext
```

Our task is to use a basic MacOS terminal to look for only those lines in the file in which the string "Word" exists at the beginning of the line and NO MORE THAN two times, and then (preferably in the same step) count those lines.

My guess was something along the lines of

```
grep "^Word" filename.txt | grep -c "(Word){1,2}"
```

but it's getting me nowhere, because the pattern for the second grep doesn't filter anything.

I'm slowly losing my mind with this problem, so I hope anyone here can help, thank you!

Comment: It's your assignment. If we do it for you, you don't learn anything. If you're having difficulties, review your course notes. If that doesn't help, ask your instructor for assistance - they need to know where they're failing to provide sufficient content.

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't this comment deny the entire purpose of this platform?This problem isn't part of the script and was never addressed in our classes, and the instructor isn't cooperative either. These things happen. Please let people live and students learn, a lot of people here explain things much better than my professor could.

Comment: Again, it's **your** assignment. Your *guess* seems to have been wrong, so try something else. We do not do homework here. If your instructor isn't cooperative, complain to your school that they are not doing the job that your tuition is paying them to do. This isn't a homework completion or code writing service.

Comment: Others are asking for help with their paid work problems, so I really don't see the problem here.

Comment: They pay people to teach regex ?

Comment: Btw, you have to use grep with the Perl option to use assertions. It's doable without assertions, but is over your head (and your instructors) understanding how to do that. Takes an expert, like _me_.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this works.  `^(Word)(?:(?!\1).)*\1?(?:(?!\1).)*$`

https://regex101.com/r/xdoxoi/1

As for counting the lines, that's not for regex.

Read version

```
 ^                       # BOS
 ( Word )                # (1)
 (?:                     # Cluster, optional
      (?! \1 )                # Any char doesn't start a 'Word'
      . 
 )*
 \1?                     # Optional 'Word'
 (?:                     # Cluster, optional
      (?! \1 )                # Any char doesn't start a 'Word'
      . 
 )*                      # Any non-'Word'
 $                       # EOS
```

Answer (score 0):

not an expert but tried something and it worked, might be an overkill:

```
grep '^bhavya' sample.txt | while read -r line; do 
   x="$( echo $line | grep -o 'bhavya' | wc -l )"
   z="$(echo $x)"
   if [[ "$z" == "2" ]]; then
      echo $line
   fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

First discard the lines with three words, the remaining task is easy.

```
sed -nr '/(Word).*(\1).*(\1)/d; /^(Word)/p' filename.txt | wc -l
```

or

```
grep -Ev '(Word).*(\1).*(\1)' filename.txt | grep -c "^Word"
```

of (When you don't like back-references)

```
grep -Ev  'Word.*Word.*Word' filename.txt| grep -c "^Word"
```